# How to fill a complex contour images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, fill

I am trying to fill an already segmented image obtained from a cross-section of a rock core (with voids in black and the material in white).

```
imageExtract = cv2.imread(path+'maskExtract.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imageExtract, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

contour_image = imageExtract.copy()

fill_image= np.zeros_like(imageExtract)
fill_image=cv2.fillPoly(imageExtract, pts=contours,color=(0,0,0))

cv2.imshow('Contours', fill_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

contour_coords = np.column_stack(np.where(fill_image == 255))

print(contour_coords.shape)
height, width = fill_image.shape
print(height,width)
depth = 10  # Profondeur de l'extrusion
volume = np.zeros((height, width, depth), dtype=np.uint8)
for coord in contour_coords:
    x, y = coord
    for z in range(depth):
        volume[x, y, z] =255
        
verts, faces,normals, values = measure.marching_cubes(volume, 0)
obj_3d=mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(faces.shape[0],dtype=mesh.Mesh.dtype))
scaling_factor=0.001
scaled_verts = verts * scaling_factor
for i,f in enumerate(faces):
    obj_3d.vectors[i]=scaled_verts[f]
print(scaled_verts)
obj_3d.save('rocheExtract_contour.stl')
```

Once I've identified the contours using the cv.findContours method, I'd like to fill the interior of the closed contours. I've tried various methods from the OpenCV library, but each time my entire image gets filled with black. The goal is to then extract a 3D file from this image. I am attaching the image I am working on :

[rock segmented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xvgb.png)

Comment: Don't forget to apply `threshold` or `canny` edge detection on your grayscale image before finding contours! If this doesn't solve your issue, please share a sample image that helps us to reproduce your issue! If the second part of your code isn't relevant to your question, please remove it. This way others can focus on your main problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already add a sample image in my post. I will try your solution.

Comment: Please show your input image

Comment: @fmw42 I can't. I have a message that say : You need at least 10 reputation to post images. If you click on the link it doesn't work ?

Comment: You can post to some free hosting service and put the link in your question or a comment.

Comment: ok thank you here is the link :https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xvgb.png